# Loading a dataframe of audio files with segmented index into a pytorch tensor

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

I'm new to pytorch, and I'm trying to prepare an input for an LSTM model of shape (nb_samples, timesteps, features).
I have a dataframe of features where the index of the dataframe is composed of the (file_name, frame) plus 40 log mel features. Here's an example :
[Dataframe example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLdME.png)

Any idea if there is some built-up function in pytorch that will let me use this information in order to prepare the input in the right shape, where the timesteps will be the number of frames (it is the same for each file already) ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think you can try and use a dataset and dataloader class but without knowing the exact transformation it will be difficult

Comment: Thank you for your help Edwin, I came across the dataloader and dataset class and I think it's a must to define that when working with pytorch. Although, regarding the transformation, can you elaborate more please; meaning what is a transformation exactly (transformation of the initial data to be fed or other) ? Thanks again